# SQL Bigquery fill null values with calculated from certain factor

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to fill null value with a new price value. The new price value will calculated from the other product available price (same product) times the factor.

given table,

```
Prod | unit | factor |  price

abc     X       1       24000
abc     Y       12      NULL
xyz     X       1       NULL
xyz     y       5       60000
xyz     Z       20      NULL
```

that formula that comes to mind

```
null price = avail same prod price * it's factor/null price factor
```

with the existing table above, examples price formula will be

```
'abc Y price' =  20000 * 1 / 12 = 2000   (avail price is abc X)
'xyz X price' =  60000 * 5 / 1 = 300000  (avail price is xyz Y)
'xyz Z price' =  60000 * 5 / 20 = 15000  (avail price is xyz Y)
```

is there any way i can do this?

Comment: what if few prices available for same prod - which one to pick for calculation?

Comment: also, it looks like in your formula you need to reverse factors  - for example `60000 * 20 / 5` - not sure, but this would look for me more logical

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant if a product has 2 or more price list, just fill the null with the lowest factor calculation

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(price,
                max(price * factor) over (partition by prod) / factor
               ) as calculated_price
from t;
```

This replaces `NULL` prices with the maximum `price * factor` for the product -- then divided by the factor on the given row.

Comment: thanks this solve my problem, but can you explain how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> if a product has 2 or more price list, just fill the null with the lowest factor

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t.* REPLACE(IFNULL(t.price, t.factor * p.price / p.factor) AS price)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT prod, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(price, factor) ORDER BY factor LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE NOT price IS NULL
  GROUP BY prod
) p
USING(prod)
```

If to apply to sample from your question - result is

```
Row prod    unit    factor  price    
1   abc     X       1       24000.0  
2   abc     Y       12      288000.0     
3   xyz     X       1       12000.0  
4   xyz     Y       5       60000.0  
5   xyz     Z       20      240000.0
```

Note: it looks like in your formula you need to reverse factors - for example 60000 * 20 / 5 - not sure, but this looks more logical for me. If I am wrong you can adjust `t.factor * p.price / p.factor` and use `p.factor * p.price / t.factor` instead

In this case result will be (which matches what you expected but as I said already I suspect is wrong -but it is up to you obviously)

```
Row prod    unit    factor  price    
1   abc     X       1       24000.0  
2   abc     Y       12      2000.0   
3   xyz     X       1       300000.0     
4   xyz     Y       5       60000.0  
5   xyz     Z       20      15000.0
```